# htaccess redirection issues

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i seem to be having some issues with my htaccess code and i am not sure why its not working, admittedly I am no expert, so any help would be appreciated.

what i am trying to achieve is this:

www.example.com/job-search.html?jobid=12345

needs to be redirected to:

www.example.com/jobs/12345

the code in htaccess that I have come up with so far is:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/job-search.html\?jobid=(.+) /jobs/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This however is not working for me, and I am not sure why, could anyone help?

Comment: What does happen when you try to visit, e.g. www.example.com/job-search.html?jobid=12345

Comment: nothing, no redirection it just gives me an error 404 as the page does not exist

Comment: Just curious why you're wanting to redirect from an "ugly" version to a "pretty" version. Are you sure that the file $WEBROOT/jobs/12345 exists?

Comment: yes it does, the reason why i am changing from the ugly version to a pretty version is basically because its a mistake. we have a 3rd party provider that assumed our urls would like "job-search.html?jobid=12345" so when they published their script they didnt check with us. so there has already been a few emails sent out with the wrong link, so I was hoping to 'correct' the wrong links and redirect them to correct urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues.

1. If you're using apache 2.0 or higher, the prefix (leading slash) of the URI is removed before being put through the rewrite engine. So the `^/` in your regular expression won't ever match. You need to remove the leading slash.
2. You can't match against the query string (the **?jobid=12345** bit) in a `RewriteRule`, you have to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable and use the **%** backreference.

So you want something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} jobid=([^\&]+)
RewriteRule ^job-search\.html$ /jobs/%1 [R=301,L]
```